# How to Connect to Informix DB from AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, informix

I am currently working on a project to connect to IBM Informix from AWS Lambda Python Environment. But so far I have not been able to find any packages or lambda layers that allows me to connect to IBM Informix DB.

Is there anyone who have been able to do so?

Or is there any lambda layers which is something similar to layer like the `pyodbc` layer from https://github.com/alexanderluiscampino/lambda-layers?

Comment: Why don't you just create a Lambda layer yourself with `pyodbc` (if that's what you're using locally to connect to Informix)? I mean, it's not even required to create a layer. You can simply install your dependencies in a folder and zip them together with your lambda function code and deploy it that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found no other ways to do so with Lambda Layers due to the 250MB size limit. The workaround for me, is to attach an EFS to my lambda function and the content of the EFS is basically `JRE` and `JDBC Driver` to allow to connect via JDBC Connection.